# CloudFront "age" header effect on "cache-control: private; max-age=3600"

Tags: http, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront, http-proxy

I am using CloudFront with fixed cache time (say 1 day) for a particular static resource.
At the same time, I want the browser to cache that only for one hour, that's why the response is:

```
cache-control: private; max-age=3600
```

However, CloudFront is always adding a response header:

```
age: 35
```

Which is the number of seconds that has been cached on the proxy (CloudFront in this case).

Reading https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching really makes sense and there's no mention of `age` header.
What is possible is that header has value of say 24678 seconds, and the resource would be considered expired.

I just want to confirm that that `age` header has no effect on the local browser cache. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately after a couple of hours of testing and experiments, it doesn't seem possible to achieve what I wanted - cache a resource in CloudFront for long period (say 1 day) but make this cached in the browser for 30 mins.

The `age` header affects the expiration of a HTTP resource.

E.g. if you have `cache-control: private; max-age=3600` and you try to fetch a resource from CloudFront with `age: 4000` then this resource is considered already expired by the browser and next time it has to be re-downloaded again.

**EDIT: October 2021**

Good news, this year AWS introduced Cloudfront Functions which exactly what we need in this case - to modify the response header that are sent to the viewer.

The two headers I modify are "date" and delete the "age" and "expiry" headers. It seems that after setting the "date" header to the current date and time, the "age" header is not added anymore (but I delete it explicitly):

```
function handler(event) {
    var response = event.response;
    var headers = response.headers;

    // Set current date
    headers['date'] = {value: (new Date()).toUTCString()};
    delete headers['expires'];
    delete headers['age'];

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for `s-max-age`? That will let you tell CloudFront to cache the resource at the edge for 1 day, but the `max-age=3600` will tell the _browser_ to only cache it for an hour. If a browser requests it at hour 2, it'll make a new request to CloudFront, but CloudFront won't make a request to the origin. The Age header doesn't really matter here.

Comment: @brett_f I see what you mean, I will test this now. But to me it seems that the effect will be the same as setting manually the cache time on CloudFront - still the `age` header will contain more than 3600 and the browser will not cache it locally.

Comment: I just had the exact same issue that the browser would not cache the resource locally. Removing the Age header (which in my case was > 100000 seconds) solved the issue and the objects are now cached in the browser according to the Cache-Control: max-age=300 header.

This seems too hacky for such a normal usecase, that I can't stop to think that we're doing something wrong....

Comment: @SilasHansen there's no hack here, I have confirmed this to be the right behaviour and also the right thing to do to work around it.

Comment: hello @NikolayDimitrov thank you for your answer, I want to confirm if for 2023 this is yet the recommended way? I am facing the same issue ("age" header forcing always full download of assets in the browser). I did a quick test with CDK adding your code, but then cloudfront returns a 503 error code with no logs in cloudwatch.

Comment: @cesarpachon yes, we are still using that code above in production without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The table mentioned in the following documentation explains how CloudFront and Browser will cache content based on different cache-control headers returned from the origin: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist

As per the doc, if your origin returns Cache-Control: max-age=3600 and your CloudFront's minimum TTL is set to 1 day then CloudFront will cache for 1 day and Browser will cache for 1 hr

Comment: If the "Date" header returned by the origin though is older than 1h - browser won't cache anything as "Age" will be over 3600. So that doesn't help unfortunately.